# How should I write a test to GTM tracking?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jestjs, google-tag-manager

I'm building an app using NextJS/React and I'm using GTM to send track events about customers. For example, sending a track event when a customer click on the button 'Add to Cart' on the product page.

Thinking about unit tests, how should I test the tracking function that builds the payload EventData with data about the product/customer and returns `window.dataLayer.push(eventData)`?

I've tried to search for some article or material about writing tests to GTM tracking events but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well push just returns true, so you probably don't want to return that. You want to build your unit tests around what you're pushing. I would typically just check what's in `window.dataLayer.slice(-1)`.

But if you don't have access to that from your unit tests, maybe just push the eventData like you do, but then return `eventData` after you push it? Or maybe also hinge it on dataLayer being defined? Something like `return typeof dataLayer === 'object' ? eventData : false`